# How to clear floats properly in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started learning `twitter bootstrap` and I was wondering what the correct method is to clear floats with it.

Normally I would just do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.main {
    float: left;
}

.sidebar {
    float: right;
}
```

Please ignore the infrastructure of the above as it's just an example.

Now say in `bootstrap` if I am trying to float some text next to a nav section what is the correct way of doing that?

Consider this example in `bootstrap`:

```
<div class="main_container">

    <header id="main_header" class="col-md-12">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        </nav>

        <div class="contact">

        </div>        

    </header>
</div>
```

I am wanting to float the `contact` field next to the `navbar` field.

I have read about bootstrap's `.clearfix` class, do I just apply this as I have done above (after the floats)? ....or should I apply the class to something else?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to utilize the proper bootstrap classes. If inside a container (a true Bootstrap container), you need a row to offset the padding.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

        <header id="main_header" class="col-md-12">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

            </nav>

            <div class="contact pull-left">

            </div>        

        </header>
</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap has `pull-left` and `pull-right` already to float content. `clearfix` shouldn't be needed if you are utilizing a container/row.

Realistically you could also (or instead) use the grid utilities on the nav/contact.

Comment: why is there no `pull-left` on the `nav`?

Comment: Well you haven't included the full nav code. Usually there is a ul with `navbar-nav` and that has a float on it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a child of the `nav` element.

Comment: You can add pull-left on the nav though. Depends on how the surrounding CSS is set up :) The trend with bootstrap navs is they generally all left float by default.